# Powershell Garbage Collector delete .Net objects which should not be deleted

Tags: powershell, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am using powershell. There is a class written in managed C++ which has C# wrapper. When i create an instance of this class in power shell and call it back later, Powershell crashes. It seems that powershell is deleting these objects. What can i do to stop powershell from deleting these objects.

'code'

```
[int] $i

{
    $i = New-Object int;
    $i = 20;
}
Write-Host $i


for( [long] $j = 0; $j -le 1000; $j++ )
{
    $newVar = New-Variable "aNewObject$j" 
    $newVar = $j;  
}

if($i -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "I is destroyed"
}
```

Here output is:
20
I is destroyed

Any ideas.

Comment: You should explain your problem with more details. What you describe so far works just fine for me.

Comment: I created Managed C++ class instance in powershell.
Then i called it later in the code. 
So sometimes when i run the whole script it works without any problem and sometimes powershell crashes. 
So i investigated it with Visual Studios I found out powershell crashes because of corrupted memory.
Each trail was with different powershell instance.
The managed C++ code is wrapper to Unmanaged C++ code.

Comment: The problem is in your C++ class or in its incorrect usage in PowerShell, presumably. I cannot give you an answer with more details because I do not know what your class is and how it should be used and where you make a mistake or where a bug is. There is not much input from you.

Comment: Sorry i cannot disclose the code. 

Thanks you for your reply. 
If anyone have similar problem and knows how to solve it please share.

Comment: I have the whole project with PowerShell, C++/CLI, C#, wrappers, etc. All works just fine if I do it fine. It's not PowerShell that deletes something that should not be deleted, it's probably your code. Debug, think. Good luck!

Comment: Ok i found the problem this sample of code actually helps to explain:
This code gives output $i is destroyed. How to specify powershell not to destroy $i..

`code`
[int] $i

{
    $i = New-Object int;
    $i = 20;
}


for( [long] $j = 0; $j -le 1000; $j++ )
{
    $newVar = New-Variable "aNewObject$j" 
    $newVar = $j;  
}

if($i -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "I is destroyed"
}

Comment: Please edit your original post to include your code example. The example that you used, has a scope issue. i.e. if you create $i (New-Object) inside the brackets, it will not exist outside the brackets and be $null.

Comment: Ok But in this case the output is 20.

`code` [int] $i { $i = New-Object int; $i = 20; } 
Write-Host $i `code`

So if the scope applies then here $i should be null too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of PowerShell scopes. This works as you are expecting:

```
[int] $i
#{
$i = New-Object int;
$i = 20;
#}
Write-Host "i is $i"

for( [long] $j = 4000; $j -le 5000; $j++ )
{
    $newVar = New-Variable "aNewObject$j" 
    $newVar = $j;  
}

if($i -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "I is destroyed"
}
```

When you set a variable inside of a scope (inside `{}`), PowerShell does a `copy-on-write` operation so a copy of the variable is modified within that scope.  This is to prevent mayhem in scripts where you don't know what variables the function who calls you is using.  Remember PowerShell uses dynamic scoping and not lexical scoping.

Also, this line:

```
$newVar = New-Variable "aNewObject$j"
```

doesn't assign anything to $newVar unless you use the `-PassThru` parameter on New-Variable.